# Call to a member function run() on a non-object code igniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am trying to design a user registration form using code igniter 2.1.0. I have used the following code in the regitration.php in controllers to add users.

```
class Registration extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'registration';

        // Checks to see if form validation rules were met an executed properly.  If not, will return with registration form.
        if ($this->form_validation->run('registration') === FALSE) 
        {
            $data ['title'] = 'Registration';
            $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
        }

        // If validation passes, information will be passed along to the MODEL to be processed and the account will be created.
        else 
        {
            $this->load->model('registration_model');
            $this->registration_model->addUser();

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Your account has been successfully created');
            redirect(uri_string());
        }
    }
}
```

But it showed me an error of `Call to a member function run() on a non-object`. How do i correct that?

Comment: $this->load->library('form_validation'); include this

Comment: I am new to code igniter. Could you please mention where i have to put this code?

Comment: did u get it working nor any error still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please include

```
// load 'form' helper
    $this->load->helper('form');

    // load 'validation' class
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
```

and try now

```
function __construct() {



    // load controller parent
   parent::__construct();   

    // load 'url' helper
    $this->load->helper('url');

    // load 'form' helper
    $this->load->helper('form');

// load 'session' 
 $this->load->library('session');
    // load 'validation' class
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

  }
```

It seems like $session class is not initializing correctly.

1. Check for default_ci_sessions table, if you are using sessions for database.
2. Check if the constructor is loading sessions library.
3. Check if session is in autoload.php config

For this `"In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file."`.
 add this to your config.php

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'your_encryption_key_here';
```

Comment: It's now showing the following error. Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::controller()

Comment: hmmm replace  parent::Controller(); with parent::__construct();

Comment: it shows the error Fatal error: Call to a member function flashdata() on a non-object

Comment: @designersvsoft any improvements?

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and effort. But now it shows "In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file.".

Comment: Yeah! Got it! It's displaying the page fine now. Thanks... Thanks so much for your effort